# Tensor flow CIFAR10 tutorial: where are image files saved?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have successfully ran [Tensorflow's tutorial on the CIFAR10 dataset](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10).

However I am unable of identifying the location on my computer to which the CIFAR10 files were downloaded.

In the `cifar10.py` file, line 54 states

```
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('data_dir', '/tmp/cifar10_data',
                           """Path to the CIFAR-10 data directory.""")
```

However, I've used Spotlight (and manual search) and cannot find this folder.

Any suggestions?

Using Python 3.5 (anaconda), TF 0.8, OS X latest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/tmp` is hidden in Finder by default.

Open up Terminal, execute `open /tmp` and you'll get a Finder window.

To show hidden files always, 
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5870/how-to-show-hidden-files-and-folders-in-finder

Comment: nice! just an additional note: this needs to be done with terminal cd'd into the folder containing the CIFAR files. I initially tried with the terminal at `~` and it didn't work. interesting, `/tmp` folder is NOT in the CIFAR folder, but instead is in `/MacPro/MacProHD/private/tmp` (`private` is hidden)